# Table count in SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, count

I copied existing SQLite database from assets to databases folder. When I tried to retrieve data from one of table(gloss) it is giving an error:

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: gloss: , while
>   compiling: SELECT DISTINCT id, fk, lang, value FROM gloss WHERE value
>   like '%a%'

I want to make sure that all tables are copied to new db inside 'data/data/package/databases/'
How to get count of tables in SQLite db?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you moving it from `/assets`? To count tables you should use this query:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM sqlite_master 
WHERE type = 'table' AND name != 'android_metadata' AND name != 'sqlite_sequence';
```

Edit**

It seems that my implementation was wrong. Use the query with the other answer.

Comment: The code is wrong; the query returns a single record containing the table count, but the code then just counts the records.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @CL from the comments:

```
String SQL_GET_ALL_TABLES = "SELECT count(*) FROM sqlite_master 
                                   WHERE type = 'table' AND 
                                         name != 'android_metadata' AND 
                                         name != 'sqlite_sequence';"
return db.compileStatement(SQL_GET_ALL_TABLES).simpleQueryForLong();
```

Comment: The cursor's count will give the  count correctly. Please explain otherwise. i am curious.

Comment: The cursor's count will give the number of records. `count(*)` will return *one* record.

Comment: If you know, please provide the answer, I will remove mine.

Comment: `return db.compileStatement(SQL_GET_ALL_TABLES).simpleQueryForLong();`

Comment: Now your answer is incomplete …